# Organizing ASP.NET Web Application Project

Tags: asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2019

How do I update references to user controls after putting `ascx` and `aspx` files into different folders?

I'm not used to working with ASP.NET Web Forms projects, but I inherited this one.  When I first received this Project, every file was directly under the root; no folders whatsoever. I've started putting files into folders and updating the paths.

When I try to load a user control, however, I get this error:

> Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.

My user control is located at:

```
myProject\controls\Widget.asxc
```

My page is located at:

```
myProject\Pages\Activity\AST_Page.aspx
```

Markup from `AST_Page.aspx`:

```cs
<%@ Register TagPrefix="tf" TagName="Cost" Src="..\..\controls\Widget.ascx" %>
```

My understanding is:

- When a user navigates to `AST_Page.aspx`, the current path is `myProject\Pages\Activity\`.
- Starting a path with `..\..\` should put me at `myProject\`.
- Therefore, `..\..\controls\Widget.ascx` actually points to `myProject\controls\Widget.asxc`.
- My Project has access to my `myProject\`.

If I change `..\..\controls\Widget.ascx` to `..\controls\Widget.ascx`, I get a different error about not finding the file, which is expected as `Widget.ascx` is not under `myProject\Pages\controls\`.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but to be safe: Are you certain neither `Pages` nor `controls` were established as virtual applications? I assume they aren't since you just created these directories—but you'd get the same error if that were the case.

Comment: Also, if only for test purposes, I'd recommend trying to call it via root relative (`/controls/Widget.ascx`) and application root relative (`~/controls/Widget.ascx`) path to see how those behave. To be clear, _all three of these should be equivalent_, but comparing their output might provide additional insight into what's going on.

Comment: The "~" gives me the same error. However, I tried a pointing to a file that didn't exist (/controls/FAKE.ascx), and  the error message changed.  With FAKE.ascx the  error is: "The file '/MyProject/controls/FAKE.ascx' does not exist."

Comment: After seeing Jeremy Caney post, I decided to commenting-out my aspx line by line.  I found a path that started with "~/../../".  Must have been from a copy and replace.  So, it had nothing to do with the ascx.

Comment: Can you just drag/drop the control onto the page and then VS will determine the path for you?

Answer (score 0):

There was a second issue on the page.  I had "~/../../" in a src attribute; likely due to an aggressive find and replace.